# convert from .c to .hex for 8051 microcontroller

Tags: c, hex, microcontroller, 8051

I need  program or site can convert from .c file to .hex file for 8051 microcontroller ?

Answer (score 3):

You need a compiler that can target the 8051 microcontroller, like [SDCC](http://sdcc.sourceforge.net/) or the [Keil compiler](http://www.keil.com/c51/)

Answer (score 0):

You need a compiler and a list with compilers are [here](http://www.intorobotics.com/8051-microcontroller-programming-tutorials-simulators-compilers-and-programmers/)